# What are the Stack Exchange goals in terms of anonymity or otherwise?

Tags: discussion, social-networking

I asked a question a while back on Stack Overflow, and there were comments on one of the answers that suggested that two users knew each other at least by username.

What are the Stack Exchange goals in terms of anonymity or otherwise?

I would say that social networks (such as Stack Exchange) fall on a spectrum between between very personal (such as Facebook) and being very impersonal. Stack Exchange has the potential to be more personal the longer a user is on the site - I've started to notice the same names answering my questions (I mostly post questions), and suspect that in a couple years if I continue using the site as I currently do, that I will be aware of a small number of users and what personal information they display about themselves.

Since Stack Exchange provides an API, would it be possible to analyze one's own network?

Comment: You're wrong to think that SE is a social network. It is not. We do not have friends or private messaging... the only way you can communicate with other users on site is through chat, which is open to all, public. That doesn't mean you can't recognize other users... we all have usernames but we can also change them at will (within set limits).

Comment: What are you asking?  People can be as anonymous as they want to be.  Some people provide their real names, addresses, and contact information.  Some people provide none of those things.  Some people get to know other people, some people don't.  You can do as much or as few of those things as you want to.

Comment: here is a kind of analysis of your *network* on Stack Overflow: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/668951

Comment: @Catija, I would say that both SE and Facebook are networks, just one is more social than the other. 'Friend' is a misnomer on Facebook - it's just a connection where you see more personal info

Comment: I didn't say SE isn't a network... I said it's not a *social* network. We don't have "connections", regardless what you call them. You can't follow people, only content (questions).

Comment: @Catija I mean, SE is a network where people interact with each other socially.  It has a very different type of social interaction than is typical of social networks on the internet, and the social connections are not the *purpose* or *design* of the site, the way it is for some other sites, and is instead a by-product.  But SE is a place where social actors interact socially in a structure, so it meets the definition of a social network.

Comment: @Servy Except that's not the *purpose* of the site. It's a byproduct. It's arguable whether the powers that be even really like Chat, which is really the only outlet for "social" interaction... Without chat, it's just a Q&A site... and most users don't use chat.

Comment: @Catija Sure, the purpose of the site isn't to create social interactions, and I said as much in my first comment.  But a social network isn't defined as a place where the *purpose* is to socially interact in a network, it's defined as a network of actors interacting socially (regardless of purpose), and SE meets that definition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What are the Stack Exchange goals in terms of anonymity or otherwise?

If you navigate to the edit profile & settings link (within your profile), you'll see within "*Web presence*" that you can (optionally) complete these fields:

- Website link
- Twitter link or username
- GitHub link or username

Apart from that, you've quite some flexibility about what you want to write in the "*About me*" section of that same page. Should you want to do so, you could mention some kind of contact info, such as your eMail ID. And you can optionally also include something in the "*Location*" field.

If however you don't want to provide/disclose such data, your profile will show something like "*Apparently, this user prefers to keep an air of mystery about them.*"

With that, I think **SE leaves it pretty much up to yourself about how much anonymity *you* want**.

> I've started to notice the same names answering my questions

There is also another way to look at what you noticed ... i.e. via the "*top users*" for any tag that you're using in your questions. As an example, have a look at some of these (Drupal.SE related) tags: [group](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/tags/group/topusers), [notifications](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/tags/notifications/topusers), [rules](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/tags/rules/topusers), [charts](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/tags/charts/topusers), [forena](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/tags/forena/topusers), [answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/tags/answers/topusers), [goals](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/tags/goals/topusers) (incomplete list ...).

Specific to those tags:

- I'm following these tags (not users!), i.e. I want to be eMailed when questions come up with these tags.
- It does happen that some users contact me to "ask for help" for questions with any of these tags, eg by posting a comment below some previous question they posted (and to which I answered).
- I'm a *(co-)maintainer* of some of these same named contributed Drupal modules (Charts, Forena, Answers, Goals), so by *answering* these questions I'm using SE as a partial alternative to *provide support* for these modules.

Comment: Following tags vs users makes sense, when comparing different networks. Thanks.